# Saving list of images in SharedPreferences coming from a database in HTML format

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Here is my API that comes with the `imagepath` from the database.

```
APIInterface api = APiClient.getApiService();
            Call<AdMain> call = api.getAd(lid);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AdMain>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AdMain> call, Response<AdMain> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body().getData().size() == 0) {
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 3.78f);
                            expandid.setLayoutParams(param);
                        } else if (response.body().getData().size() == 1) {
                            Picasso.with(ShowNotesActivity.this).load("http://124.41.193.135:88/" + response.body().getData().get(0).getImagePath()).into(imgad);
                        } else {
                            imagepath = new ArrayList<>();
                            imageadlist = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getData().size(); i++) {
                                imageadlist.add(response.body().getData().get(i).getImagePath());
                                endIndex = i;
                            }
                            Log.d("size", "onResponse: "+imagepath.size());
                            nextimage();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AdMain> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Now I want to save these images coming from the database in my SharedPreferences in HTML format.

Comment: Images in Html Form ? How Explain pls.

Comment: no not in html form just it comes the path of image /1.jpeg. and using the base url + imagepath it will display image and i need the whole image save in sharedprefrence show that if the internet is now available it can display image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   public String getImageUrl() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .getString("url");
    }

    public saveImageUrl(String url) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putString("url", "").commit();
    }
```

If you want save a image list, there're some other [options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for you

Comment: its url means the whole url or something what i didnt understand. url = "baseurl"+imagepath or what. can u explain in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that image to base64 and can save that in shared preference

```
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
    String imageString = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about it `caching`. You can cache image in storage which are loaded once from Internet and load them from cache next time. For caching
You can read [Caching bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html) Or you can use Image loading libraries which provide a very efficient way for caching and makes image loading/caching bread and butter.below are some references you can use .

[Link1](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[Link2](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

[Link3](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)